# Add up time from DateTime in PHP

Tags: php

I'll try to explain my problem. I am beginner with PHP and need help manipulating Date/Time.

So here is my situation.

I get Date/Time values from the database in this format: 07/02/2017 11:00 pm

First I need to calculate a difference between two dates and output duration.

Then add up duration and output total time.

The code is very dirty as I am just researching now. I also came to a problem that DateTime does no carry over points. As far as understand I need to convert days to hours and add them up.

Can anybody more experienced make sense of this?

```
$total_time = new DateTime('00:00');

$start_date = new DateTime('2017-05-01 12:20 PM');
$end_date = new DateTime('2017-05-01 12:30 PM');

$interval = $start_date->diff($end_date);

$total_days = $interval->days;
$hours      = $interval->h;

if ($total_days !== FALSE) {
    $hours += 24 * $total_days;
}
$minutes    = $interval->i;


$total_time ->add($interval);

echo $hours .'hours ' . $minutes . 'minutes';

echo $total_time->format('h:i'); ?>
```

Comment: Try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: store them as actual date formats in the db, the you can do all this with a sql querry

Comment: I do calcuate the difference between two dates. Just how to add the time together. I cannot store anything on the database. This has to be done with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a DateInterval to the DateTime.

You can check on http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Looking at your code:

```
$total_hours = 0;
$total_minutes = 0;
//must be initialized outside of the while loop

$start_date = new DateTime('2017-05-01 12:20 PM');
$end_date = new DateTime('2017-05-01 12:30 PM');

$interval = $start_date->diff($end_date);

$hours = $interval->h + 24*$interval->d; /*there is no need to check
if you have total days, since 0 days would still work as expected */

$minutes = $interval->i;

echo 'Duration: '.$hours.' hours '.$minutes.' minutes';

$total_hours += $hours;

if(($total_minutes += $minutes) >= 60) {
    $total_hours += 1;
    $total_minutes -= 60;
}

//after the end of the while loop

echo 'Total time:'.$total_hours.':'.$total_minutes;
```

Now I don't understand what is the expected output of total time, if you can elaborate on what is not working it would be easier to help

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: That would be great :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post any try at helping with the code because I don't understand what is the expected result from $total_time, you want to add the duration to what starting date?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it clearly. This code will be in a while loop getting start and end date/time from the database. It will calculate duration and count total duration. Conversion to hours was because if duration is longer than 24 hours PHP seems to output it in days variable.

Comment: I'hv updated the answer, should be enough to solve what you have described.